# Expression has changed after it was checked - Event subscription updates

Tags: angular, angular-lifecycle-hooks

Though I know the reason as to why this `ERROR` happens, However, I would like to know how to overcome in the following scenario:

I have a generic loader in `app.component`. For some of the child routes it'll update the loader value on `ngOnInit` life cycle until records are fetched. Also, I do not want to use `resolver` as I'm parsing the query params in the component and then passing to the service to fetch the records.

The `ERROR` is due to the default value of the loader to `false` and changes to `true` during the child component life cycle `ngOnInit` hook.

Please have a look at the following snippet:

```
// app.component.ts
 viewModel = {
    showLoader: false
};
ngOnInit() {
    this.eventService.on(ApplicationEvents.SHOW_FULL_PAGE_LOADER, (value) => {
        this.viewModel.showLoader = value;
    });
}
// app.component.html
<div class="full-page-loader" *ngIf="viewModel.showLoader"><em class="fa fa-cog fa-spin loader-icon"></em></div>
```

And following is the snippet from the lazyloaded child component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
    this.cart = this.cartService.getCart();
  }

private loadData() {
this.eventService.showFullPageLoader(); // <-- This will emit an event to show the loader 
this.umrahDataService.getServices(UmrahServiceType.Visa).then((resp) => {
  this.visas = resp.map((v) => {
    v.image = '/assets/img/umrah/visa-processing.jpg';
    return v;
  });

  this.eventService.hideFullPageLoader();
  this.actionInProcess = false;
}).catch((er) => {
  this.alertService.alert('SERVER_ERROR');
  this.eventService.hideFullPageLoader();
  this.actionInProcess = false;
});
}
```

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'.
>       at viewDebugError (core.js:19629)
>       at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:19617)
>       at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:19833)
>       at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:29533)
>       at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:29522)
>       at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:30126)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:30054)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:3)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:30043)
>       at checkNoChangesView (core.js:29421)

Although I tried `BehaviorSubject` with `async` pipe as well and that didn't help either.
Looking forward for the feedbacks.
Thanks

Comment: What is the exact exception message?

Comment: @AshokanSivapragasam Updated question. Please check.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you change data after view has been loaded, let Angular watcher to digest the changes. Angular has ChangeDetectorRef service. You can inject this service and force the angular to detect and include the changes in the digest cycle.

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-comp',
  templateUrl: 'your-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['your-comp.component.scss']
})
export class YourCompPage {
    constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        ..any data changes or your flag in this case..
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        // -- OR --
        this.eventSubscription.someEvent(() => {
            ..any data changes or your flag in this case..
            this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        });
    }
}
```

P.S. https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I did try running `CD` manually as well.
`this.cd.detectChanges();` but that didn't work.

Comment: According to this article and Yuriy, it is better to do it in ngAfterViewInit() and change-detector for digesting. https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error/

Comment: Nope. `ngAfterView` is throwing the same error however, I've added a hidden class but rather to remove the div from the DOM. Though I am still looking forward for the actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases moving your reactive code to `ngAfterViewInit` helps. So in your child component instead of:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
    this.cart = this.cartService.getCart();
}
```

use

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadData();
    this.cart = this.cartService.getCart();
}
```

You could also use `setTimeout` in your `app.component.ts`, but that is more like a hack rather than a solution.

Comment: Looking for solution not for hacks!

Comment: @Cleancode using `setTimeout` is a hack, while `ngAfterViewInit` is quite a clean solution IMO.

Comment: Well, something needs to be done on `ngOnInit` life cycle shouldn't be pushed `afterViewInit` due to specific issue. This is a hack bro!

Answer (score 0):

Angular change detection Process is Synchronous, to avoid this error we can make this as async process, and we can make that code to run outside of Change Detection by doing something like.

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {    
     this.interval = window.setInterval(() => {
      this.eventService.on(ApplicationEvents.SHOW_FULL_PAGE_LOADER, (value) => {
      this.viewModel.showLoader = value;
      });
  }, 1)});
};
```